# Sort order in SparkSQL array_agg

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, presto

I have a table that looks like this:

| sensor | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| near | 2 | 0.3 |
| near | 3 | 0.8 |
| far | 2 | 0.2 |
| far | 5 | 0.0 |
| far | 4 | 0.1 |

I'd like to create an aggregated table that looks like this:

| sensor | values | times |
| --- | --- | --- |
| near | [0.3, 0.8] | [2, 3] |
| far | [0.2, 0.1, 0.0] | [2, 4, 5] |

The values and times arrays are both ordered by ascending time.

I am using this query:

```sql
SELECT sensor,
  ARRAY_AGG(value) AS values,
  ARRAY_AGG(time) AS times
FROM sensor_table
GROUP BY sensor
```

But `ARRAY_AGG` puts the values in an arbitrary order. With Presto, I can do this:

```sql
SELECT
  sensor,
  ARRAY_AGG(value ORDER BY time) AS values,
  ARRAY_AGG(time ORDER BY time) AS times
FROM sensor_table
GROUP BY sensor
```

But SparkSQL does not allow the `ORDER BY` syntax. How can I do this in SparkSQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with also using [`array_sort`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_sort) and [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform).

```sql
WITH sorted_structs AS (
  SELECT sensor,
         ARRAY_SORT(
           ARRAY_AGG(st),
           (left, right) -> case when left.time < right.time then -1 when left.time > right.time then 1 else 0 end
         ) AS sorted_struct_array
  FROM (
    SELECT
      sensor
      struct(value, time) as st
    FROM sensor_table
  ) as sensor_struct
  GROUP BY feature_key
)

SELECT sensor,
       TRANSFORM(
         sorted_struct_array,
         sorted_struct -> sorted_struct.value
       ) AS sorted_values,
       TRANSFORM(
         sorted_struct_array,
         sorted_struct -> sorted_struct.time
       ) AS sorted_times
FROM sorted_structs
```

You first put the `value` and `time` in a struct, and then aggregate the struct values into the array. You can sort the struct based on the `time` value.

With `transform`, you can then split up the values again to different columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_sort`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_sort):

> Sorts the input array. If func is omitted, sort in ascending order. The elements of the input array must be orderable. NaN is greater than any non-NaN elements for double/float type. Null elements will be placed at the end of the returned array.

```sql
SELECT sensor,
  array_sort(ARRAY_AGG(value)) AS values,
  array_sort(ARRAY_AGG(time)) AS times
FROM sensor_table
GROUP BY sensor
```

Comment: I'd like to sort both arrays by the `time` value in each row. For example, the `values` for the `far` group should end up in descending order because `value` descends with respect to `time` in the `far` group.